# Resize UITextView when keyboard is presented (Swift)

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextview

I would like the textview to resize when the keyboard is on screen so the user can still see what is underneath. How would I go about doing this? Should I have notifications? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keyboard notifications (e.g. `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`). There is no need to resize the text view; just resize its content inset (and its scroll indicator inset).

Comment: Downloadable example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p532textViewAndKeyboard/ch23p811selfSizingTextField/ViewController.swift

Comment: Amazing! For IOS 8, especially since there isn't ANY Swift support for a UIViewAnimationCurve raw value of 7 which is what's returned for the keyboard animation curve user value in the notification message (that's the approach used by some older solutions based on earlier iOS and Objective C). I wanna get me a book :-)